# How to skip enum name passing its variant to a macro?

Tags: rust, enums

I would like not to mention each time the enumname which contains the variant supposing it's always the same. Is it possible?

the key thing there is in a **struct** variant in the enum.

on a more mundane level:

I've tried the following:

```
enum Types {
  t1,
  t2{id: u64}
}

macro_rules! createenum {
  (enum $enumname: ident { $( $variant: ident ( $arg1: literal, $arg2: expr ) ,)* } ) => {
    enum $enumname {
      $( $variant, )*
    }

    impl $enumname {
      fn arg2(&self) -> Option<Types> {
        match self {
          $( $enumname::$variant => Some(Types::$arg2), )*
          _ => None
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

createenum! {
  enum MyEnum {
    Var1("one", t1),
    Var2("two", t2{id: 5}),
  }
}
```

Evidently the code above does not work, since rust does not know what the `t1` and `t2` are. But I am loath to type the base enum each time.

How should I go about it?

Comment: Please don't add the solution inside the question. Instead [you can add an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and accept it once SO allows you do do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use Types::*;` [Rust Playground demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=220e8ee7f7f060e35cb3e5720212bef1)

Comment: Everything is simple, truly. It's better to put it inside the function.

Comment: @dronte7 Yep, that works too.